# php not working on ubuntu desktop 16.04.02

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

I need php < then 5.3 becouse software I inherited use mssql library.

SO I have set up linux, and apache (working fine via localhost or ip) then:

I get libxml in version below 2.9 (otherwise make php will not work - compiler will lack some older libraries I belive)

```
sudo wget ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz #get package
sudo tar -xvf libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz  #unpack
cd libxml2-2.8.0 #:) rest is quite obvious
sudo ./configure 
sudo make
sudo make install
```

So I have libxml instaled and go with php same way

```
sudo wget http://museum.php.net/php5/php-5.2.17.tar.gz
sudo tar -xvf php-5.2.17.tar.bz2
cd php-5.2.17
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

All seems to be ok, except php is not working. Apache doesn't include it so php page output looks exacly same a code like:

```
both in code and webpage: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
<?php
echo "BBBBBBBBB";
?>
```

What I found so far:

```
check mods-enabled - I have no php mod at all there

uncomment #LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so - I don't have this line at all i apacheconf

run a2enmod php5.2.17 - return "module php5.2.17 doesn't exist"
```

Comment: Have you tried using a recent PHP release with the [Microsoft PHP Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server)?

Comment: That would require redeveloping all aps, and some of them are very big (I estimate months of working). From what I read in short: it's not that easy to replace mssql code to new driver... and quite frankly I will use PDO instead of MS solution - at least I will have some guarantee, they won't abandom it.

Comment: ubuntu 16.4 doesnt support php less than 5.6

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25302891/building-php-5-5-from-source-in-centos-missing-mod-php) will help. As you built PHP yourself you also have to build the Apache module for it. Then add `LoadModule php5_module path/to/your/libphp5.so` to your `httpd.conf`.

Comment: You mean if I install <5.6 it won't be working, and that that? Or do you mean the don't give any guarantee? If first that would explain many things :) What version of ubuntu I need to install to get 5.2.x working?

Comment: Comment from Joe seems promising. I will try.

Comment: I followed Joe's solution but its not that easy: correct command to install httpd-devel in ubuntu is: `sudo apt-get install apache2-dev` then I reconfigured, recompiled and reinstaled php and I have file php5.load in enabled mods in apache but when I ruch apache config test I get: `cannot load libphp5.so .... undefined symbol: unixd_config` - from what I read php5 apache module is missing in ubuntu 16, so I run `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5` but I get `Package has no instalation candidate`. I've tried multiple versions of this command. I'm stuck again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved my problem by instaling ubuntu 14.04 (maybe later I will update it to 16, and maybe old php will still be working), ale then by instaling LAMP in 1.2.4

This version can be found here: https://community.bitnami.com/t/where-to-find-lamp-stack-running-php-5-2-for-old-software/31209/12

**Ubuntu must be 32 bit!!!**

How to instal .run file?

```
sudo chmod +x lamp.1.2-4 
sudo ./some-app.run
```

what is worth to change too in php.ini:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE 
display_errors = On 
short_open_tag=On
```

htdocs is in: /opt/lampstack1.2-4/apache2/htdocs
Php ini is easily find via phpinfo() function

basic operations (in opt/your lamp directory:)

```
sudo ./ctlscript.sh restart apache
sudo ./ctlscript.sh status
```

Alternative is here https://askubuntu.com/questions/597462/how-to-install-php-5-2-x-on-ubuntu-14-04 - I managed to do it all (mentioned links to patchs are broken), but in the end php5 module that I had to install newest 5.x php so I ended with 5.6.xxx against my will :)

I could not make mssql to work so far, but I will ask new question for this.

Hope this helps somebody.