# Ubuntu 14.04 + Lamp 1.2.4 mssql_connect is not working

Tags: sql-server, linux, apache, ubuntu, lamp

I'm strugling with a linux to install serwer for older php app. I have instaled ubuntu 14.04 + lamp 1.2.4 and I have made everything working except old mssql functions.

Obvioulsy I uncomented, and restarted apache:

```
extension=php_mssql.dll
```

and So far I tried:

```
apt-get install php5-sybase php-pear
pear install --nodeps MDB2_Driver_mssql
```

from https://www.turnkeylinux.org/forum/support/20090708/enabling-ms-sql-support-lamp-stack

in phpinfo I don't have mssql section at all.

here is a litle bit more about how I instaled linux: [php not working on ubuntu desktop 16.04.02](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44693701/php-not-working-on-ubuntu-desktop-16-04-02/45166257#45166257)

Comment: that link is really old... a simple `apt-get install php5-mssql` should work... but what are the error messages? maybe something else is missing or the syntax has changed?

Comment: Error message on php page is `Fatal error:call to undefined function mssql_connect()`. I tried command you sugested but I get `selecting php5-sybase instead php5-mssql.... php5-sybase is already newest version... 0 upgraded, 0 newly instaled and 694 not upgraded` - it looks like mssql is instaled, but sth is missing anyway to make it work with php.

Comment: Another thing: from what I see sybase (or pear command) have created new directory `/etc/php5/mods-avaiable/` where I see file `mssql.ini` in with I see `extension=mssql.so` (but I don't know where that file is if it is att all). In `/opt/lamp/apache2/modules` I see *.so files but not mssql.so

Comment: Where possible you should really look to utilise Linux containers for running older environments like this. It could possibly save you a lot of hassle in the long run.

Comment: yes, in ubuntu/linux the extensions are *.so, not *.dll . AFAIK ubuntu 14.04 should have a helper to enable mods: try `phpenmod mssql` to follow the ini structur for the php package or write the line `extension=mssql.so` directly at the end of your php.ini file

Comment: `phpenmod mssql` - it returned "No such command". I added `extension=mssql.so` to php.ini but it still doesn't work. How can I locate this file in linux to make sure it's there at all. If it's NOT there, can I download mssql.so like I would download mssql.ini and put it in proper directory? (What directory?)

Comment: by mssql.ini I meant mssql.dll ofcourse :P sorry

Comment: `find / -name mssql.so` returns 0 files found. I don't understand why `apt-get install php5-sybase php-pear` didn't create it. and the only mssql.so I found via google is 64bit. Any source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really answer to this question, but my goal was to have a linux with php 5 and working mssql* functions. And this is how I finaly did it. It's quite easy once you know that under windows mssql was out in php 5.3.x but in linux it's **not until php 7**. (all my attempts to install a choosen version of php with stuff I need failed, and from what I see nobody has answears so linux is much more difficult to work with then I anticipated).

This I think is really nice tutorial for total beginer, hope it helps somebody:

**Ubuntu must be 14.04 and NOT above** (they switched to php 7).

SOME BASIC STUFF:

```
sudo apt-get install mc /*midnight commander is REALLY helpfull*/
sudo apt-get install konqueror /*or conqueror if you have deskptop*/
sudo nano file /*this is how you easily edit file in xterminal*/
sudo nano gedit file /*and in desptop*/
```

APACHE:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2    /*install*/
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
add this line: ServerName 192.168.0.xxxx    /*your ip or server name*/
sudo apache2ctl configtest /*if sth is wrong*/
sudo service apache2 restart
```

PHP

```
sudo apt-get install php5 /*php itself*/
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5 /*mod that connects php with apache I belive*/
sudo apt-get install php5-sybase php5-odbc freetds-common /*all libraries are required*/
sudo service apache2 restart
```

FAQ for php.ini (location of file is in phpinfo() )

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE /*will disable notices*/
display_errors = On
short_open_tag=On /* <? will work instad of <?php only */
```

How do I install modules?

```
sudo apt-get install mcrypt php5-mcrypt
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

That made it work for me.

Comment: I created such a nice tutorial for linux begginers to have older php + mssql, and yet somebody gave -1 :P .... should be reqired to give reasons.